# track path of recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to track path of a deep nested value in json object but having hard time getting the path. Each Item is an array of objects and can have child items. If the object `c` exists in the json data it is always located in the last item array.

```
item: [
{
    a:5,
    item: [
        {
            item: [
                {c:1},
                {x:4},
            ],
            ...
        },
        {},
        {}
    ]
},
{},
{}
]

const findPath = (items) => {
    let path = []

    items.forEach((item,i) => {
        if('item' in item){
            path = path.concat(findPath(item.item))
        }
        else if('c' in item) {
            path.push(i)
        }
    })
return path
}
```

if I have 3 `c` objects with different item depths, then I would have:

```
[
  [0,0,0], //item[0].item[0].item[0].c
  [1,0], //item[1].item[0].c
  [4]] , //item[4].c
```

Any help?

Comment: What output are you getting? And what output are you expecting?

Comment: @kenef the function now just returns the last item array index. I want each index of the nested items

Comment: Your `else if` condition is wrong. It can never be true. Can you see why?

Comment: @Holli I am able to print each c value so not sure if what you saying is correct.

Comment: Indeed, but this is true: Recursion always makes my brain melt.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is that you don't track the common case. You store the index only when you found a leaf, but you want all the steps in between. This being recursion, you also have to carry your return values with you, or you end up stepping on them. This works:

```
objects = [
    {},
    {
        item: [
            {},
            {},
            {
                a:5,
                item: [
                    {
                        item: [
                            {c:1},
                            {x:4},
                        ]
                    },
                    {},
                    {}
                ]
            },
            {}
        ]
    }
]

const findPath = (items, current_path, matching_paths) => {
    items.forEach((item,i) => {
        if('item' in item){
            current_path.push(i);
            current_path = current_path.concat( 
                findPath(item.item, current_path, matching_paths) 
            );
        }
        else if('c' in item) {
            current_path.push(i);
            matching_paths.push( current_path.slice() );
            current_path = [];
        }
    })
}

var path = [];
var paths = [];
findPath(objects, path, paths);
console.log(paths); //[[1, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Your solution returns undefined. I solved it anyway.

Comment: The return value is irrelevant. You need to look at `paths`.

Answer (score 0):

If `C` is found push a path object to the path array and update that path object for the rest of the paths.

```
const findPath = (items) => {

     let path = []

     items.forEach((item,i) => {

         if('item' in item){
             let item_path = findPath(item.item)

             if(item_path.length > 0){
                 item_path[0].path.push(i)
                 path.push(item_path[0]) 
             }
        }
        else if('c' in item){
            path.push({path:[i], c:item.c})
        }
     })
     return path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function must be recursive, which means it should call itself with different parameters and not loop forever.
Below is what you are looking for. I made it in TypeScript to make sure I typed it correctly, but just take off all type definitions and it becomes JavaScript:

```
const trackPath: number[][] = [];
function findPath(topItem: any, path: number[], position: number): void
{
    const currentPath = path.slice();
    currentPath.push(position);
    const newTopItem = topItem['item'];
    if (Array.isArray(newTopItem)) {
        // here is the recursion for each subitem
        newTopItem.forEach((item, i) => findPath(item, currentPath, i));
    }
    if ('c' in topItem) {
        trackPath.push(currentPath);
    }
}

// this is the main method to call
function actuallyGetThePath(myTopItem: any): number[][] {
    findPath(myTopItem, [], 0);
    return trackPath;
}
```

Good luck!